# Swift 2.0 copyFile EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

Been updating some code to 2.0 and my replaced copyFile routine is returning
"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
The // line was how I was doing this previously.

```
 class func copyFile(fileName: String) {
    let dbPath: String = getPath(fileName as String)
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(dbPath) {
        let fromPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName , ofType: "db")
        // let fromPath: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
        do {
            try fileManager.copyItemAtPath(fromPath!, toPath: dbPath)
        } catch _ {
        }
    }
}
```

How do I go about resolving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resourcePath` returns optional value just use `?` before using any method

```
let fromPath: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
```

Also `URLByAppendingPathComponent` is not a member of `NSString`. Did you mean `resourceURL`?

In that case use this

```
let fromUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourceURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
let fromPath: String = (fromUrl?.path)!
```

Comment: In the latter case I get "Cannot convert value of type NSURL? to specified type string"

Comment: Yes this works:

class func copyFile(fileName: String) {
        let dbPath: String = getPath(fileName as String)
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(dbPath) {
            let fromUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourceURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
            let fromPath: String = (fromUrl?.path)!
            do {
                try fileManager.copyItemAtPath(fromPath, toPath: dbPath)
            } catch _ {
            }
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work

```
class  func copyFile(fileName: String) {
  let dbPath: String = getPath(fileName as String)
  let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
  if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(dbPath) {
    //let fromPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName , ofType: "db")
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath
    {
      let fromPath = "\(path)/\(fileName)"
      fileManager.copyItemAtPath(fromPath, toPath: dbPath)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Had to add a try in as it wanted to try and trap errors: if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath
            {
                let fromPath = "\(path)/\(fileName)"
                do {
                    try fileManager.copyItemAtPath(fromPath, toPath: dbPath)
                } catch _ {
                }
            }